# What's wrong in this CODE AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'div'

Tags: python

I have created a module named as "cal.py"

```
import math    
import operator

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def subtraction(a, b):
    return a - b

def mul(a, b):
    return a * b

def div(a, b):
    return a / b
```

When I try to do following in python intrepreter

```
>>cal.div(10, 2)
```

its shows

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'div'
```

whereas, for `add()` its given me correct answer

```
>>cal.add(4, 7)
11
```

Comment: Then you probably are importing a different `cal` module, *or* you forgot to reload the module (restart your interpreter or use `reload(cal)`) after editing.

Comment: Super!!! Thank you its working ... I just restarted the interpreter.